# How to build a figure with a fixed height and an img and figcaption that flex to fill the space

Tags: image, flexbox

Situation: I want a `figure` that has an `img` and a `figcaption` stacked vertically. The `figure` should be `100vh` high, the `figcaption` its natural height (i.e. it could split onto two lines, or the user could change the text size), and the `img` should flex to take the remaining space.

I’ve got a solution that works if the image is initially smaller than the viewport: https://codepen.io/robinwhittleton/pen/XWYaqyg. But if you edit that pen to an image size of 2000x3000 (i.e. bigger than the viewport) it breaks.

Sample HTML:

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/eee?text=2:3"/>
    <figcaption>Figcaption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Sample CSS:

```css
figure {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

img {
    object-fit: contain;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

I’ve tried a bunch of stuff now but either I’m fundamentally misunderstanding this, or it’s not really possible to do (which seems unlikely). Any ideas? This is going into an ePub so the ideal solution will work on slightly older WebKits, but at this point I’d just be happy with a solution that’s working in browsers.

Comment: Could you please clarify _how_ it breaks? I'm looking at your pen and I'm not sure what you mean is "breaking"?

Comment: You need to adjust the pen to a vertical dimension greater than the height of your viewport. The expected behaviour is that both the img and figcaption will fit within the viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is you force the image height into zero, then stretch it out again by using `flex-grow`. The image will be distorted, then using `object-fit` to fix it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

figure > img{
    height: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/eee?text=2:3"/>
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image will be scaled down.

```css
figure {
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr auto;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
}


body { margin: 0}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300/eee?text=2:3"/>
    <figcaption>Figcaption caption caption caption caption caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```